# Android: Backwardscompatible ( Android L -> Jelly Bean )

Tags: android, compatibility, android-5.0-lollipop

So I've created an Android L application but I want it to be compatible with 4.3 and up,

My folders in **res** looks like this

```
values-v18
   theme.xml
values-v19
   theme.xml
values-v20
   theme.xml
values-v21
   theme.xml
```

My **manifest.xml** ( Android Studio says its being ignored since I have the gradle )

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="18" android:minSdkVersion="18" />
```

My **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.+'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 'android-18'  <-- this breaks all Android-L stuff
   buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'
   ....
```

The values-v21/**theme.xml** is where it fails, such as

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'android:Theme.Material.Light'
```

and with all android-L-only things.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as far as I know, it is only possible to use `minSdkVersion` of `L` when using things of L.

Comment: So they released a developer preview for the app-makers around the world to start developing apps for the new Android. But no way you can fit it together with your already existing app? This cant be true! :(

Comment: It's a hard-knock life for us, programmers :)

Comment: Its a _PREVIEW_ not even a candidate release. The Android team is looking for problems in the L API before its set in stone.

Comment: Wow, it's that simple, huh? :(

Comment: It may HAVE been a preview but it's still problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write targetSDK=21. It is can help. By tag android-l you can also find some sl solutios of this trouble.

Comment: That alone won't help in compiling things like android:Theme.Material.Dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="21" android:minSdkVersion="18" />
```

and/or

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-21'
    ....
```

Android L is API 20 and Material theme is only available for API 21+ (you will be warned for the minSdkVersion you use but the compilation will work)